# event is not defined in mozilla firefox for javascript function?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

```
function onlyNumeric() {   
    if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
        event.returnValue = false; 
    }

}

onkeypress=onlyNumneric();
```

In IE, this code is working fine. However, in Mozilla Firefox, the event is an undefined error.

Answer (score 16):

In FF/Mozilla the event is passed to your event handler as a parameter.  Use something like the following to get around the missing event argument in IE.

```
 function onlyNumeric(e)
 {
     if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
     }

     ...
 }
```

You'll find that there are some other differences between the two as well.  This [link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey2.shtml) has some information on how to detect which key is pressed in a cross-browser way.

Comment: Age old problem.. age old solution... Wonder when we'll get over the Browser wars! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Or quite simply, name the *parameter* **event** and it will work in all browsers. Here is a jQueryish example:

```
  $('#' + _aYearBindFlds[i]).on('keyup', function(event) {
  if(! ignoreKey({szKeyCodeList: gvk_kcToIgnore, nKeyCode: event.keyCode }))  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  });
```

This example allows digits only to be entered for year fields (inside a for each loop selector) where ingoreKey() takes a keyCode list/array and compares the event keyCode and determines if it should be ignored before firing the bind event.

Keys I typically ingore for masks/other are  arrow, backspace, tabs, depending on context/desired behaviour.

You can also typically use event.which instead of **event.keyCode** in most browsers, at least when you are using jQuery which depends on event.which to normalize the key and mouse events.

I don't know for sure what happens under the covers in the js engines, but it seems Mozilla FF respects a stricter scope, wherein, other browsers may be automatically addressing the **window.event.keyCode** scope on their own when the event is not explicitly passed in to a function or closure.

In FF, you can also address the event by **window.event** (as shown in some examples here) which would support this thought.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers may not support keyCode you have to use keyChar

```
function onlyNumeric() {   
    var chars = event.keyCode | event.keyChar;
    if (chars  < 48 || chars  > 57) {
        event.returnValue = false; 
    }

}

onkeypress=onlyNumneric();
```