# Event Handlers in Firefox vs IE/Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, firefox, cross-browser

I'm working with some event handlers, and am getting a bit confused as to one aspect.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553240/event-is-not-defined-in-mozilla-firefox-for-javascript-function) thread, Firefox adheres to WC3 standards and passes click events as a parameter to your handler. You can then access this event by coding `MyHandler(event)`. However, what if you're passing another parameter already?

Specifically, my onClick function is `editItem(this)` where `this` refers to the table row that was clicked. However, I need to call `event.stopPropagation()` inside the `editItem` function in order to prevent some other handlers from going off. In IE and Chrome, this works, but in Firefox, `event.stopPropagation()` gives me a null pointer, which makes sense because I'm not taking in an event parameter into `editItem(this)`.

My question is, how do I take in both `this` and `event` in my onClick function? Can I just append them like `editItem(this, event)`? How will Firefox know which one is the event and which one is my personal parameter?

Comment: I very much recommend the excellent articles about event handling at quirksmode.org: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html (yes, all of them).

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Bookmarking for after work. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `editItem(this, event)` as you mentioned.  Then your function just needs to be defined like this:

```
function editItem(element, event){
   ...
}
```

It will know which parameter is which because of the order of the parameters.

Comment: Eggselent. I forgot that "event" was a special identifier. :)

Comment: @TheDramaLlama It's not a special identifier.  It's just that on* HTML attributes are compiled into functions that take a single argument called "event".

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So it's "special" in the sense that it's functionally special, but not nomenclature-wise?